# Convert jpg image in ppm P3 ASCII format using Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, jpeg, ppm

Using opencv imwrite function I managed to convert jpg image in ppm P6 format.

```
Mat image = imread(picPath);

vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY);
compression_params.push_back(1);

imwrite("bez.ppm", image, compression_params);
```

Problem is that I actually have to convert jpg image in ppm P3 ASCII format.
Does anyone know how to do it? 
Thanks!

EDIT:

In the project I have the following piece of code where I check the maximum value of pixels:

```
int maxVal; 
fscanf(in, "%d", &maxVal); 
if (maxVal != 255)
{ 
    printf("Input file error: Not a Netpbm color image with 256 levels\n");
    exit(0); 
}
```

When I set parameter 0 then I get: Not a Netpbm color image with 256 levels!

When I do the conversion from jpg to ppm p3 with irfanview program works.

Comment: `compression_params.push_back(0);` maybe?

Comment: When I set parameter 0 then I get: Not a Netpbm color image with 256 levels (maxVal!=255). When I set parameter 1 then I get: Not a Netpbm ASCII portable bitmap.

Comment: Is this part of a larger project? If not, you can convert from JPEG to PPM (P3) with ImageMagick (which is included in most Linux distros and available for OSX and Windows) very simply in the Terminal like this `convert input.jpg -compress none output.ppm`

Comment: This is part of a larger project code. Use of other programs is out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code involved is in the file `modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_pxm.cpp` in the OpenCV source tree.

It sets the internal flag `isBinary` like this according to the compression parameters:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < params.size(); i += 2 )
   if( params[i] == CV_IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY )
      isBinary = params[i+1] != 0;
```

so, if you want ASCII (P3) you need to have

```
compression_params.push_back(0)
```

and have image type CV_8UC1, CV_8UC3 or CV_16UC1.

Comment: In the project I have the following piece of code:

        `int maxVal;
 fscanf(in, "%d", &maxVal);

 if (maxVal != 255){
  printf("Input file error: Not a Netpbm color image with 256     levels\n");
  exit(0);
 }`

When I set parameter 0 then I get: Not a Netpbm color image with 256 levels!

When I do the conversion from jpg to ppm p3 with irfanview program works.

Comment: irfanview begin of image: P3
# Created by IrfanView
2560 1920
255
142 126 113 ...

openCV begin of image: P3
2560 1920
255
 142 126 113 ...

Comment: You are confusing me now :-( It's hard to read code in the comments area - it's better to click `edit` underneath your question and update it so that all the information is cleanly formatted and in one place. I don't understand why you are doing `fscanf()`, which is a read, when your problem is writing.

Comment: Is your input image definitely an 8-bit BGR image?

Comment: input image: 2560x1920 RGB image with bit depth = 24